# Show MD5 Password in user section

Tags: users, password

Im trying to show the MD5 Password of the users as you see them in the database but in the users table as an extra column.

I have previusly done with the ID like this:

```
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'cmr_suid_execute' );
function cmr_suid_execute(){
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'cmr_suid_add_uid_col');
    function cmr_suid_add_uid_col($columns) {
        $columns['user_id'] = 'ID';
        return $columns;
    }

    add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'cmr_suid_show_uid_col_data', 10, 3);
    function cmr_suid_show_uid_col_data($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        if ( 'user_id' == $column_name )
            return $user_id;
        return $value;
    }
}
```

But I try this with the Passwords and it doesnt work... Am I missing something?

```
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'cmr_supwd_execute' );
function cmr_supwd_execute(){
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'cmr_supwd_add_upwd_col');
    function cmr_supwd_add_upwd_col($columns) {
        $columns['user_pass'] = 'MD5 Password';
        return $columns;
    }

    add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'cmr_supwd_show_upwd_col_data', 10, 3);
    function cmr_supwd_show_upwd_col_data($value, $column_name, $user_pass) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_pass );
        if ( 'user_pass' == $column_name )
            return $user_pass;
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: edit you question to add debugging details https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: As you can read in [the documentation on `get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/), this method only accepts the `$user_id` as argument, not another column of the user. You _could_ try [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) instead, but this is a **really bad idea** because what if 2 users have the same password?

Comment: Thanks @kero that seems to be the problem :S
Is there any way to show them all even if some of them uses the same password?

Comment: its not md5. ...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get MD5 password in user listing column, you have to get `user_pass` using  `get_userdata().` see below example how to get `user_pass` from `get_userdata()`

```
add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'cmr_supwd_show_upwd_col_data', 10, 3);
function cmr_supwd_show_upwd_col_data($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'user_pass' == $column_name )
        return $user->user_pass;
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works amazingly well! :)

Comment: stop saying its md5 its a hash but it's not md5. your making people think that passwords are still hashed with md5 but they are not.

Comment: please update your answer to mention this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.

Comment: Wordpress uses MD5 Password hashing. Creates a hash of a plain text password. Unless the global $wp_hasher is set, the default implementation uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5. MD5 is used by default because it's supported on all platforms

Comment: In the older version, WordPress used MD5 hash to encrypt passwords. Since WordPress 2.5, it started using stronger encryption technologies. However, WordPress still recognizes MD5 to provide backward compatibility

Comment: Fair enough, that is useful information. 2.5 is also ancient. Hashing 8 times is, well, not the same as once with md5. I still think hashed password would be the better term for it, since different hashing algorithms can be used depending on the version.